# Caching Generic types of Objects with Redis using C#

Tags: c#, caching, redis

I'm creating a new feature here in my application to cache using AOP.
When my method is called using `RedisCacheableResultAttribute` I will cache / retrieve the data.
I'm successfully storing, don't know it's the correct way serializing and storing as string, but when I return the object from Redis I need convert to the type I stored at the first time. 
I imagine that I can do it with reflection but no success, i'm not very experienced with reflection.

```
public sealed override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
{
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    var result = cache.StringGet(args.Method.Name); // retrieving from Redis

    if (result.HasValue)
    {
        args.ReturnValue = result; // here I need to convert back to the type I received when I stored.
        return;
    }

    base.OnInvoke(args);
    cache.StringSet(args.Method.Name, Serialize(args.ReturnValue)); //storing the data OK.
}

private string Serialize(object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem with the following solution:

In the input method where I am using the Apsect I changed the types to Dynamic. Using object works too.

```
[RedisCacheableResult]
public List<dynamic> ReturnCustomer()
{
    var lstCustomer = new List<dynamic>();

    var customer = new Customer
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Acme Inc",
        Email = "acme@email.com"
    };

    var customer1 = new Customer
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Marvel Inc",
        Email = "Marvel@email.com"
    };

    lstCustomer.Add(customer);
    lstCustomer.Add(customer1);

    return lstCustomer;
}
```

On Deserialize:

```
private static dynamic Deserialize(string data)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(data, Settings);
}
```

Segue a solução publicada no **GitHub**: https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/TestaCache

Issues, pullrequests, stars and forks are welcome :)

Comment: What is the settings you are using there?

Answer (score 3):

No need for reflection here, just use **JsonSerializerSettings** to save your type in data blob:

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeHandling = TypeHandling.Object };
```

Then put it into serialization and deserialization methods:

```
private static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, _settings);
}

private static object Deserialize(string data)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, _settings);
}
```

Then in code:

```
public sealed override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
{
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    var result = cache.StringGet(args.Method.Name); // retrieving from Redis

    if (result.HasValue)
    {
        args.ReturnValue = Deserialize(result);
        return;
    }

    base.OnInvoke(args);
    cache.StringSet(args.Method.Name, Serialize(args.ReturnValue));
}
```

For faster solution, I recommend you to use another Newtonsoft format called BSON (binary json), it will convert your object into byte array considerably faster than to string. So as long as you don't care about readability, it will be wise to use it.

I did not test it, so can be compilation errors, but Newtonsoft has their ways to save type, so you should not bother about it.

Comment: I will test it soon! Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm testing here,
TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects 
 Because I didn't found TypeHandling

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CacheApi.Customer]'.'

Comment: Yes, it is what I meant.

Comment: My original object who calls:   
[RedisCacheableResult]
public List<Customer> ReturnCustomer()

Comment: With your advice will try to go deeper now and investigate

Comment: I will try BSON now

Comment: I make it work but not in the way that I want,, If in the call I send the object for example List<object> GetCustomer.... I can return List<object> and it works.. If my method who fire this event it's a typed doesn't work, he complains about the type, can't Cast it, keep investigating, but your help was essential to continue, thanks again.